# How to dismiss the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have used the below code to show the view with partial curl effect.
And it works fine but I want to know that how can i `dismiss` the `popoverViewController` when touching the curl effect as like in the map application in the iphone.

thanks for any help

```
 UINavigationController *navPop = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverViewController] ;
    [popoverViewController release];

[popoverViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];


    [self presentModalViewController:navPop animated:YES];
```

actually i know the code to dismiss the view but , wat i need to know is i want to dismisss it by clicking on the curl effect.. this is wat i would like to know

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method.

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually i know the code to dismiss the view but wat i need to know is i want to dismisss it by clicking on the curl effect.. this is wat i would like to know. any help

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `modalTransitionStyle` of wrong object, I guess. As you are presenting `navPop` you should set the property to it:

```
[navPop setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
```

When you would like to `dismiss` it, just call:

```
[navPop dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And you will see `curl effect`